# ReactJS Test - fsevents is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, npm, typeerror, react-scripts

I am trying to write test cases for my program and I heard good things about `testing-library/react` and `jest-junit`. I used npm to install both packages into my `devDependencies` and change my script for test: `"test": 'react-scripts test"` When I run npm test, I get and error saying

`TypeError: fsevents is not a function`

So I tried to npm i fsevents but it did not help. I tried looking online but the errors there were either fsevents is not a constructor or change to yarn.

What is causing this issue? I am using npm v6.4.1 and react-script v3.1.1

Edit: Also using a Mac if that matters

Edi2: I ran the test again and did not get this error anymore without changing anything.

Answer (score 46):

Had similar issue on OSX. If you have `Homebrew`, just run following command in terminal and try again:

```
brew install watchman
```

If it doesn't help, try running following commands in terminal:

```
sudo rm -rf (xcode-select -print-path)
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: I had the same issue, ```brew install watchman```  command solved my issue. Thanks

Comment: Anyone using port instead of brew can run `sudo port install watchman`.

Comment: I used expo with react native and couldnt open my app on my emulator/phone etc. and the error said: "Cant connect to the node server, make sure you started it correctly...", this was also the solution for the problem when I had it. `brew install watchman`

Comment: `brew upgrade watchman` solved my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 13):

Any time I did create-react-app, I got this exact error when I immediately ran 'npm test'.  This worked for me if I already was committed to the React project:

```
npm install fsevents@1.2.11
```

After some digging, I found out that I needed to manually install this package because CRA pumped out several

`npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.11 ...`

messages during the initial install.  And yet, I needed this package to run 'npm test'.

However, my bigger issue was that CRA was skipping this dependency install because it wasn't detecting xcode on my system.  I was getting these messages:

```
gyp: No Xcode or CLT version detected!
```

The solution is to run the command

```
xcode-select --install
```

Now, any future create-react-app's should operate smoothly without needing any additional dependency installs!  [Additional Xcode troubleshooting here.](https://github.com/schnerd/d3-scale-cluster/issues/7#issuecomment-402541605)

Comment: You made my life easy. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue after a fresh install of node and create-react-app. After some searching I found this article [1] about a known issue with running npm test.

After installing watchman, tests are running.

[1] https://github.com/bbc/simorgh/wiki/Known-setup-issue-when-running-%60npm-test%60

Comment: the url doesn't lead to an article (at least not anymore)

Answer (score -2):

`fsevents` is installed by default with `npm` on Mac OS and Windows operating systems. The error `"is not a constructor"` might mean you tried to initialize `fsevents` in *your* code. Most likely with the `new` keyword. Please review your code for this, if not let me know.

Comment: But the error is ```is not a function```, would that be the same thing as not a constructor?

Comment: Most likely. If you do use `fsevents` in your code, please show me that part of the code and explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: I ran the command again today and it worked fine. I do not understand what went wrong since I didn't change anything between my last test and my most recent one

Answer (score -2):

what you have to do is very simple. Run the following

```
rm -rf node_modules/ package-lock.json
```

and then

```
npm i
```

This worked for me.

Comment: to remove your package-lock is really not recommended... it can cause a lot of issues related to dependency versions and more - you should definitely know what you do when you removed your package-lock.
there are lot of resources to understand what it it is - starts with this one:
https://medium.com/coinmonks/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-package-lock-json-b81911aa8ab8